# Rails - Polymorphic nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-url

I have a polymorphic model "Item" setup so that it can belong to either subdivisions, divisions or places.

Routes I'm trying to achieve are:

```
/category
/category/place
/category/place/item **
/category/place/division
/category/place/division/item **
/category/place/division/subdivision
/category/place/division/subdivision/item **
```

** Item can belong to a place, division OR subdivision. never more than one. I'm using Friendly_ID to create these slug urls.

My routes.rb file currently looks like this:

```
resources :categories, path: ''
get ':category/:place', to: 'places#show', as: :place
get ':category/:place/:item', to: 'items#show', as: :item
get ':category/:place/:division', to: 'divisions#show', as: :division
get ':category/:place/:division/:subdivision', to: 'subdivisions#show', as: :subdivision
```

Currently, I can only have one "item" setup in my routes. How do I make "item" accessible through either place, division or subdivision?

Comment: I can't see any _question_ in the question. :)

Comment: Ah, it was implied - I've edited to make it clearer. My routes.rb file currently only has one "item" route, and ideally I would like an item to be accessed via 3 possible routes - as it can have one of 3 possible parents.

Answer (score 0):

You can point all of those routes to `items#show` i.e.

```
get ':category/:place/:item', to: 'items#show', as: :place_item
get ':category/:place/:division/:item', to: 'items#show', as: :division_item
get ':category/:place/:division/:subdivision/:item', to: 'items#show', as: :subdivision_item
```

Comment: This looks great! Can I ask - would this be the right rail-sy way to solve this, and how would this also support all "item" show actions using the same html layout?

Comment: Would this approach also stop my other routes from working? Specifically the "division" and "subdivision" routes, as the app would be expecting the id of an item, and receive the id of a division.

Comment: @Kobius yes, that would conflict with those routes. You will need to add static parts in between to separate them. i.e. you could use items as `get ':category/:place/items/:item', to: 'items#show'` to differentiate it from the other routes.